# Converting System.Data.DataTable to System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, converters, sqldatasource

I know how to convert a datasource to a datatable, however I like to know if it is possible (and how) to convert a datatable back to a datasource?

Answer (score 0):

You probably not want to convert. The SqlDataSource is used to make an SQL Query to the database. So I think that the convert DataTable to SqlDataSource is not possible.
From SqlDataSource you can create a DataTable (using the result of the SqlDataSource's Select method as the DataTable.

```
var result = SqlDataSource1.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
var enumeartor =  result.GetEnumerator();
enumeartor.MoveNext();
DataTable dt = ((DataRowView)enumeartor.Current).Row.Table;
```

But this requires at least one row in the result. Otherwise you get an Exception I think.